# Javascript framework that handles routes natively (changing state)

Tags: javascript, frameworks, routes, meteor

After working with meteor for a bit I realized that meteor doesn't have native support for route handling. So I've been looking around and now am wondering what are some of the full stack JS frameworks that handle routes.

Basically have functionality similar to Meteor but be able to handle routes natively. Building one page applications that essentially change their state when the URL changes.

With pros/cons (most actively developed) and so on.

Comment: Meteor is the most actively developed framework in its class today. It's got a great core of developers with mountains of cash to work with. But there is a currently unresolved question about just how much should be in the Meteor core, and how much should be left to 3rd party packages. Geoff Schmidt's take on this from one of the dev talks seems to be the some of these features that many frameworks have built in (like routing, models, validation, form scaffolding, etc) may eventually be added to the core, but they want to see more of what the community has to offer before locking down any APIs

Comment: Makes sense, I've decided to stick with Meteor. I'll just be using one of the meteor plugins like `iron-router`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meteor community has accepted [iron-router](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/iron-router) as the way to do client side routing.

```
$ mrt add iron-router
```

The full documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router).

Comment: But it seems like it hasn't been in active development. Last commit was a month a go and on top of that there are lots of unresolved issues.

Comment: It's under very active development by key figures in the community - note the branches. The master only gets bumped when it's stable, and meteor is undergoing a lot of changes as it heads towards 1.0.

Comment: Will Meteor bundle iron-router or some other sort of router in the core in the future or is that not part of their plan?

Comment: This is currently under debate. The present thinking is that it's been successful so far w/o being integrated so there isn't a hurry to do so. On the other hand, a router seems like a pretty important component. Long term, I suspect it will become a core package.

Comment: Great, one more thing just wondering if the `mrt` command is a `meteorite` command? Because I've installed meteor without meteorite and am wondering how to go about adding iron-router? I've tried `meteor add iron-router` but it can't find the package.

Comment: Yep, `mrt` is the meteorite command line tool. It's installed via `npm`. See [this](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/app) for instructions.